# Why JSON in Java doesn't Implement Serializable

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have recently come in a need to serialize JSON. In Java we can't serialize as Java as it doesn't implement serializable.I can convert it to string and serialize, while retrieving read as a string and convert the string to JSON.

But there is an overhead of converting to string for serialization and converting string to JSON after deserialization.

the solution I'm thinking to avoid this is serialization & deserialization very simple. we can rewrite code with every Class in org.json.* to implement serializable

And my question is why JSON doesn't implement serializable.
Does it have any specific reason to avoid this

Comment: The whole point of JSON is to exchange structured data, formatted as text, using the JSON syntax, writable and readable in any programming language. Not to exchange binary data as native Java serialization does, that can only be read by Java code. Your idea is basically equivalent to printing a text file, taking a picture of it, and sending the JPEG file, instead of just sending the text file.

Comment: JSON already is a serialization format, a text-readable serialization like XML, making your question sound like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever problem you're trying to solve, making JSON serializable isn't likely the solution that you want.

Comment: @aravinth If you want Serialization why use JSON at all? Why not serialize the original objects? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I want it to be both serializable with java processes & exchangeable to other things

Comment: Even worse. Why do the same thing two different ways?

Comment: I can avoid the cost of constructing json from string between Java processes

Comment: You can avoid that cost by paying the cost of Serialization, *and* 1/2 the cost of JSON (the encoding part), and your poor client gets to pay the cost of you implementing everything twice. This isn't making any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP I didn't find anything wrong in implementing twice Do you consider it as anti pattern !?

Comment: Double the cost to the client. Double the code; double the coding time; double the debugging. Space and time wasted in the executing code. I'm astonished you even asked the question. And there is still nothing here identified as a 'need'. Just a self-evidently foolish idea that you will save something. You won't.

Comment: @EJP What is meant by wasting time ? I think it will provide the client in a faster way possible

Comment: I have already disproven that completely in about seven different ways. What exactly would it take to convince you? How exactly can it be faster to convert an object to JSON and then serialize that and then deserialize it and then convert the JSON back to an object, rather than doing half those things? The idea is completely absurd.

Comment: Sorry, I'm accepting all those things but regarding time, I'm still thinking it will be faster

Comment: You're accepting that doing four things instead of two can't be faster but you still think it will be faster? Is there any chance of keeping this discussion on a *rational* basis?

Comment: Thanks for the thanks, but it would be better to provide some indication that you have grasped what you're being told here.

Comment: @EJP avoiding json serialisation, I can reduce my workload & client will be same across all platforms. Thanks again for your patience. ☺️

Comment: I agree, so why are you asking how to serialize JSON, which presumes a prior JSON serialization step? This is what I have been asking you since the beginning, and you haven't answered it.

Answer (score 3):

Objects that implement `Serializable` will generally be serialized using native Java serialization algorithm (documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html)).

JSON is meant to work with any language, but the native Java serialization will only work with Java (and even then it's quite brittle).  Thus, on this occasion, implementing `Serializable` makes no sense.

Comment: Serializable doesn't have anything to do with JSON but doesn't harm any JSON I think. So that when the transfer between two Java programs it could be better I assume

Comment: `Serializable doesn't have anything to do with JSON` - that's exactly the point, and why it's not used.

Answer (score 0):

**Why do we need Serialization?**

Serialization means conversion of object to byteStream, its purpose is to maintain the state of object. By word 'state' it means value of variables or reference to other object. The byte stream obtained after serialization can be stored in database or it can be used over network for communication with remote client/server.

**Use of Serialization**

Serialization is used so that it can be deserialized (we can get the saved state of the object) in the future. When we deserialize we specify the object in which we wish to convert.

**JSON means JavaScript Object Notation.**  Its a notation of JavaScript object and **not** java object.  Its a notation and not an actual object.

Java don't know how to read javascript object and hence it can't serialize & deserialize JSON. So when you convert json to String. java knows how to serialize & deserialize String Object.

Comment: 'Java does not know how to read JavaScript object and hence it can't serialize & deserialize to JSON': the `org.json` package does exactly that. You've completely missed what this question is actually about.